# Tableau: How do I force a bar chart to display all dates when cycling through a filter?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a range of data that starts 8/1 and updates every day with the number of calls we got. I have a filter that splits out the calls by department. If I select a department that got no calls yesterday, the graph realigns to have the top date as the day before yesterday.

how do I force the graph to always use the maximum date that's in the data?

Comment: Will their be any value in database if the particular department doesn't has the data for calls for a day?

Comment: The database includes all contacts (calls and emails) for the day, and I am filtering on calls only. When I cycle through the department filter and reach a department that had no calls on that day, the result set will not have any values for that day, though the unfiltered data does have values with that date, does that make sense? If I were to make a calculated field that simply takes the maximum date value in the data, that would work, but I don't know how to apply that to my bar chart to force it to that range.

Comment: Can you share workbook with sample data?

Comment: I may be able to do this later this evening.

Comment: Actually it will be easy to understand add our solution in a workbook